# Solr search with query string @ returns all the records

Tags: apache, solr

I am facing an issue with solr search while search " @ " it returns all the records .How to fix this scenario, if there is no record with @ symbol also it returns all the records.

Below one is my url

> http://localhost:8983/solr/oneteam/select?q=caption:/.*@.*/ OR description:/.*@.*/

can any one help me out of this.

Thanks in adv.

Comment: What is the analyzer attached to the field you're trying to search? Remember that you might have a tokenizer that splits on `@`, meaning that you're efficiently searching for anything matching anything at all (`.`). You probably want a `string` field to make any regex searches useful.

Comment: Please find as below.

Comment: <field name="caption" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The analyzer and filter sequence attached to the default definition of the field type `text_general` [uses the `StandardTokenizer`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html#Tokenizers-StandardTokenizer):

> The "@" character is among the set of token-splitting punctuation, so email addresses are not preserved as single tokens.

This means that `@` signs are not kept, since they're used for splitting the text instead. If you need the `@` to be kept to search for it, use a `string` field type instead (and if this is a search that will be performed often, you might want to condense it down to a field that only contains `1` if the document matches the search (i.e. the field contains an `@`) to avoid having to perform a regular expression against all the values for the field in the index.